# Is this a gsettings bug?

Tags: gnome, desktop-background, gsettings

I have this script, that changes my background image to a random darkened one every couple of minutes with gsettings that I have hooked up with a cron job.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the directory containing the images
IMAGE_DIR="/home/me/images"

# Select a random image from the directory
IMAGE_FILE=$(find "$IMAGE_DIR" -type f | shuf -n 1)

# Define the output path for the processed image
OUTPUT_IMAGE="/tmp/background.png"

# Adjust the brightness (reducing it, e.g., by 70%)
convert "$IMAGE_FILE" -fill black -colorize 70% "$OUTPUT_IMAGE"

# For Wayland sessions (common in Ubuntu 22.04 and later)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u)/bus

# Set the processed image as the background
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark "file://$OUTPUT_IMAGE"
```

Now this generally works fine once the system is up and running, but each time I re-start the system, the background stays black. It starts to work again once I manually set the background in the settings app, so the cron job and script are fine. Script also runs without complaint, desktop just stays black.

The solution I found was to first use the same setting with an empty parameter, like this:

```
# Set the processed image as the background
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark ""
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark "file://$OUTPUT_IMAGE"
```

This workaround is not very good though, as the switch between images now breaks at in weird ways. I have to resort to a two script solution, where I set the background to nothing on startup and then let the cron job handle the rest. But this seems to be a bug in my view. Any ideas if this is intended?

PS: For now I have modified the workaround, so that it checks if a background image is already present in the temp folder, though I didn't really test it yet.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the directory containing the images
IMAGE_DIR="/home/me/images"

# Select a random image from the directory
IMAGE_FILE=$(find "$IMAGE_DIR" -type f | shuf -n 1)

# Define the output path for the processed image
OUTPUT_IMAGE="/tmp/background.png"

# Check if the script is running for the first time in the session
if [ ! -f "$OUTPUT_IMAGE" ]; then
    # Set the background to nothing first
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark ''

    # Wait a bit for the reset to take effect
    sleep 1
fi

# Adjust the brightness (reducing it, e.g., by 70%)
convert "$IMAGE_FILE" -fill black -colorize 70% "$OUTPUT_IMAGE"

# Set the actual background image
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark "file://$OUTPUT_IMAGE"
```

Comment: when you shutdown and start the system, is it happening too? I just want to confirm the behavior same for restart and a fresh start.

Comment: Yes, a full shutdown does the same.

Comment: Should be reproducible, as this is pretty much a stock Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop installation.

Comment: I guess some permissions issue. Is running cron job requires sudo?

Comment: No, it's  a user context thing. I have added a workaround to my post that I'll let run from now and see if it causes problems. Though I still think this is a bug in the gsettings tool. I tried to reset the value instead of setting it to empty too, but that was acting up too.

Comment: Can you try without dark uri and see?? Also it seems that convert command also taking some time?